# Node.js Command line does not execute

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 Server, which I want install Node.js.

I execute following commands:

```sh
root@ubuntu:~# curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get install nodejs -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (10.16.3-1nodesource1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.


root@ubuntu node -v

Command 'node' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install nodejs


root@ubuntu:~# which node
root@ubuntu:~# which nodejs
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried restarting your terminal?

Comment: Yes, I restart my Server and Terminal at my NoteBook

Comment: ok maybe potential fix here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/404929/node-command-not-found

Comment: sudo apt install nodejs

Comment: I look in the `usr/bin` directory. there is no node or nodjs file

Comment: I use the root User, so I think, I do not use sudo. ;-)